# SIGCHLD handler in c - unwanted wait

Tags: c, signals, sigchld

I've the following problem with the SIGCHLD handler function.

The handler code is pretty simple:

```
void sigchld_handler(int signum)
{
    pid_t ended;    
    signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);
    ended = wait(NULL);
    // do some stuff with the PID of the finished child process
}
```

This works well when I fork only one child. If I have 2 children (or more) and one of them has finished running, the sigchld_handler() starts and when it gets to the "ended = wait(NULL)" line, the program waits until the other child I have finishes.

Is there a way to get the PID of the child that just ended in a different way and avoid this wait?

Comment: why do you call `signal()` inside the signal handler ?

Comment: Not sure I understood you. I use the signal() on the 2nd line to save the setting for the other processes, there is no further use in it. The "do some stuff" are not related and there is no call to signal() again.

Comment: What do you mean by "save the setting for the other processes" ? only the parent process receives the signal, I think it has no effect at all here.

Comment: @mux: if you use `signal()` rather than `sigaction()`, then (for many signals) the signal disposition is automatically set to `SIG_DFL` before the signal handler is called.  Setting the signal disposition so that the handler is called might be necessary.  You'd need to scrutinize the man pages carefully; there are different implementations of `signal()` — BSD has 'reliable signals', for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes but he's calling `signal()` again inside the signal handler, it is specified as a safe function by POSIX so I guess it's okay, but I'm not sure why ?

Comment: Because, as I said, the signal handling is changed by the o/s so that the signal handler for SIGCHLD is SIG_DFL, not `sigchld_handler` — if you use `signal()` instead of `sigaction()` and if your version of `signal()` does that.  Old school Unix (pre-dating `sigaction()`) required that every time, for SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGTERM, SIGHUP, etc.  7th Edition UNIX didn't have SIGCHLD at all.  The behaviour opens a window of vulnerability; two signals arriving sufficiently quickly may kill the process despite the handler's best efforts to stop it.  This is why `sigaction()` is better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, I didn't read the man page for signal, that explains it, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sigaction()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead, the handler will have this signature:

```
void (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
```

And it's passed the information you want in `struct siginfo_t`, from the man page:

> SIGCHLD fills in **si_pid**, si_uid, si_status, si_utime and si_stime,
>   providing information about the child.  **The si_pid field  is  the 
>   process  ID  of  the child**

Note: you still need to `wait()` on the child process of course, unless you use `SA_NOCLDWAIT`.

Comment: AFAIK, you still need to call `waitpid()` or `wait()` to ensure that your process doesn't accumulate zombies.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, unless `SA_NOCLDWAIT` is used, anyway, I'm just answering the part about getting the child pid.